# Problems with localization of .storyboard files

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Trying to make my project using storyboard.

I changed my info.plist and added entry UIMainStoryboardFile with the name of my storyboard file and other things from documentation. I added new storyboard-file to my project (it was created in Xcode 4.1 and now I'm working with it on 4.2), made interface that i need and decided to localize it.

After adding localizations for it in File Inspector and localizing each file, I don't see any changes when I run the app. Even if i change all localized files, I still see app like it looked before adding localizations in File Inspector. I tried to delete this file and create a new one with another name, but the result was always the same.

When I create a new empty project and do the same thing everything works fine. Or when I remove all localizations for my storyboard-file, everything works too.

What can I do to fix it? What did i miss?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Had the same problem. Solved it by doing a clean, deleting all derived data in filesystem (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Derived Data) and deleting the App from Simulator.